# Require root package version with Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm developing a Laravel application that can be extended by different packages. These extension packages are installed using Composer. So for example if I want to add the project management module to an instance of the application, I can run

```
composer require app/projects
```

add the service provider of the package to `config/app.php` and be done. These packages are specifically meant to extend my "core" application and not for any other use.

So my question is: Is it possible for the "extension" packages to require a specific version of the "core" root package? So for example the `app/projects` package version 2.0 requires the root package version 2.0 as well and can't be installed if the root package has version 1.0. Can this be done?

Comment: circular dependencies are a bad idea.

Comment: @tkausl Do you have a better idea? Some extension versions only work with some root package versions and you can't avoid that. Look at the plugin management of, say, Wordpress; it's a similar situation there.